GetFileByServerRelativeUrl in ADF: 400 Bad Request Error
I am trying to copy data from Sharepoint File to ADLS Gen 2 Storage Account and my URL Looks like this:
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/AWSreStack-01GlobalAWSreStack/Shared%20Documents/01%20Global%20AWS%20reStack/07%20Reporting/2024%2001%20AWS%20Pipeline%20Reporting/Data%20for%20PowerBI_Don%27t%20move%20or%20delete/AWS_Pipeline_Targets_For_Data_Pull%20.xlsx

While creating the Relative URL Path I get the following error:
ErrorCode=HttpRequestFailedWithClientError,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Http request failed with client error, status code 400 BadRequest, please check your activity settings. If you configured a baseUrl that includes path, please make sure it ends with '/'.\nRequest URL: https://xyz.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/sites/AWSreStack-01GlobalAWSreStack/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/AWSreStack-01GlobalAWSreStack/Shared%20Documents/01%20Global%20AWS%20reStack/07%20Reporting/2024%2001%20AWS%20Pipeline%20Reporting/Data%20for%20PowerBI_Don%27t%20move%20or%20delete/AWS_Pipeline_Targets_For_Data_Pull%20.xlsx')/$value.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Net.WebException,Message=The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.,Source=System

Relative URL:
/:u:/r/sites/AWSreStack-01GlobalAWSreStack/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/AWSreStack-01GlobalAWSreStack/Shared%20Documents/01%20Global%20AWS%20reStack/07%20Reporting/2024%2001%20AWS%20Pipeline%20Reporting/Data%20for%20PowerBI_Don%27t%20move%20or%20delete/AWS_Pipeline_Targets_For_Data_Pull%20.xlsx')/$value

Any help regarding this would be really helpful. Thanks!

The issue is with the URL you are using to access the file.
The URL to access the file should look like below.
Base URL : https://[sharepoint-domain-name].sharepoint.com

Relative URL : /sites/[sharepoint-site]/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/[sharepoint-site]/[relative-path-to-file]')/$value

To get the URL go to your file >> details >> and copy the path and use it to create base URL and relative URL as above.


Hi, thanks for the help. I generated the URL as you suggested and Base URL looks like this:
Base URL: https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/AWSreStack-01GlobalAWSreStack/Shared%20Documents/01%20Global%20AWS%20reStack/01%20AWS%20Reporting/05%20AWS%20Pipeline/Data%20for%20PowerBI_Don't%20move%20or%20delete/AWS_Pipeline_Targets_For_Data_Pull%20.xlsx
I generated the Relative URL  using it but still got the exact same error.

Relative URL generated using Base URL:
/sites/AWSreStack-01GlobalAWSreStack/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/AWSreStack-01GlobalAWSreStack/Shared%20Documents/01%20Global%20AWS%20reStack/01%20AWS%20Reporting/05%20AWS%20Pipeline/Data%20for%20PowerBI_Don't%20move%20or%20delete/AWS_Pipeline_Targets_For_Data_Pull%20.xlsx')/$value

in this URl try replacing %20 with space

I removed spaced but still got the same error:
New Relative URL: /sites/AWSreStack-01GlobalAWSreStack/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/AWSreStack-01GlobalAWSreStack/Shared Documents/01 Global AWS reStack/01 AWS Reporting/05 AWS Pipeline/Data for PowerBI_Don't move or delete/AWS_Pipeline_Targets_For_Data_Pull .xlsx')/$value

Have you gave proprt permission to service printipal to access the sharepoint?

Hi, yes- the Service Principal and my Account has permission on the file and it's parent Folders. Still this 400 Bad Request Error pops up.
